# How to migrate windows instance from Azure to Compute Engine without lost of any data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to migrate windows instance from Azure to Compute Engine without lost of any data
How to migrate windows instance from Azure to Compute Engine without lost of any data

Comment: I tried to create image, but there is inacceptable boot device BSOD

Comment: 1) Without the correct licensing agreement with Microsoft, you cannot legally migrate Windows Server. Google with verify your license. 2) You will need to use a third party product to create an image suitable for import into Compute Engine. 3) If all you need is a copy of the "data", use a back program and restore on a new instance in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate a windows instance from Azure to compute engine, you should follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/migrate-azure-to-gcp/overview), which is a guide from Migrate for Compute Engine.

In the guide, it shows some steps needed to prepare the environment, which are, in summary:

1. Set up GCP as a migration destination.
2. Set up network.
3. Set up azure credentials in Migrate for Compute Engine.
4. Configure Migrate.
5. Perform a migration test.

After you have done the steps contained in that link, you can now [perform the migration](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/migrate-azure-to-gcp/migrating-azure-vms).
For Windows Machines, your runbook (aggrupation of machines being migrated) must contain a valid [license string](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/reference/runbooks).

About license strings. GCP supports, for windows, 2 licensing methods. BYOL (Bring your own license) and PAYG (Pay as you go) here we have 1/2 options, depending on the [WS version](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/concepts/planning-a-migration/vm-os-licensing#windows-license-strings):

a. If you already have a license key for the OS (note that azure pay as you go licenses are not supported in GCP), then choose the BYOL license, or

b. If you want you use a GCP provided one, use PAYG.

After the migration is finished, your VM data is intact, and the only thing that you will have to do is turn the VM on again.